# Where can I find information on getting started with Selenium 2?

Tags: selenium2

Some background.  I am a long time [WatiN](http://watin.org) coder, and have been since I first looked at Selenium a few versions ago, and decided that it didn't meet my needs, and then went with WatiN.

I now want to switch to selenium 2 (selenium web-driver).

What are the best resources? Where can I can find out about getting started with Selenium 2?

I am personally interested in the C# API, how control mapping works, and implementation examples. [Selenium HQ.org](http://seleniumhq.org/) still talks primarily about Selenium IDE and the older versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebDriver documents are available at -

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html
http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html

Does it help?

Comment: Being in the exact same boat as Bruce, the first link has very very basic information, and the second link is mainly 'to do'.  I'm still finding it more useful to go through the method definitions in the dll's.

Comment: let us be more specific about kind of implementation example and/or control mapping being soughed here. May be I could help

Comment: Please note that those docs are in the process of being revised for the upcoming Selenium 2 release. There are other resources available for information about Selenium WebDriver. Another answer already indicated the [Google group for WebDriver](http://groups.google.com/group/webdriver). Another resource is the #selenium IRC channel on Freenode where many of the core developers frequent.

Answer (score 1):

I think a truly complete introduction to Selenium 2 is non-existent actually. But the project is still in beta-phase so it is a little understandable.

For C#, I would recommend starting here :

http://code.google.com/p/design-of-selenium-tests-for-asp-net/

If someone is looking for something less specific, The best I could recommend is going over the project's wiki : 
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/w/list

Especially those ( preferably in that order) :

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/NextSteps

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesignPatterns

A good place to look for more information on Selenium is the official Selenium blog :
http://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think the Google Groups site is as good of a place as any for information:
http://groups.google.com/group/webdriver/topics

Answer (score 1):

I have a suite working in C# on a heavy javascript application. I found [Selenium 2 Testing Tools: Beginner's Guide](http://www.packtpub.com/selenium-2-testing-tools-beginners-guide/book) to be a great resource to figuring out the Page Object Pattern and other important Selenium concepts for writing a clean, informative, modular UI testing suite.  I also recommend to focus on running your tests regularly on all the configurations you wish to test on (all browsers, domain, IE!, etc.) rather than writing as many tests as possible and fixing all the bugs later on other browsers / domains / configurations. Also in a javascript heavy app, [explicit waits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7312740/1111732) are your friend, this was a long barrier for me to finally get Selenium to be useful.