# I am looking for online Training or Books or online resources on selenium automation testing

Tags: selenium, training

I am looking for training on selenium automation testing. I would like expertise on selenium.

I have walk-through following books but all are very beginner

Selenium 1.0 Testing Tools: Beginner's Guide by David Burns

Selenium Simplified by Alan John Richardson

Selenium Testing Tools Interview Questions by Vibrant Publishers, USA

Please let me know best online training you know or you had attended 
best website links for Selenium learning
Best books for selenium

Comment: Can you please explain why someone who has a personal site called learnseleniumautomation.blogspot.com is asking how to learn about selenium. This post feels very spammy to me, and is a is a duplicate of http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/295/where-can-i-find-information-on-getting-started-with-selenium-2

Comment: I am voting for closing this question

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, the Selenium site itself does not provide much educational material.

Judging from your blog, you are more interested in Selenium as a Java API than as a capture/playback tool.  I think that is the right choice, but it does require some programming skills.  Your blog has articles on elementary Java programming, e.g. "Branching Statements in Java for Selenium Automation".  I do not know whether that means you are new to Java as well. I will assume that you are.

I think there are three or four areas you need to study to be effective at writing Selenium automation: the Java language, HTML, XPath, and Javascript.  If you are comfortable with all of those, you will be comfortable with Selenium too.  You do not need to be an expert, but you need to know enough that you know where to look for answers and feel confident that you can figure things out.  You may have better luck finding well-written reference materials for those areas than finding an advanced-level Selenium book.

Some people seem to like using "page objects" in their Selenium automation.  I am not one of those people, but a Google seach should turn up plenty of references.

Answer (score 2):

Its very fortunate  that you have been able to walk-through all the books mentioned in your question. Once you have also gone through the  useful suggestions provided in the earlier post, which I am sure you would be able to run through /grasp in no time, you could try adding another crucial ingredient to your learning ,that would "test" your learning  and also teach you something simultaneously:

> I would term this 'resource' as  'Real-time learning' . Apply whatever you have learnt so far,  on problems/project you are working/interested  in. This would identify any areas you made need more focus and at the same time reinforce your strengths.
>
> If the areas you need focus on can be found by revisiting  the books and suggestions previously suggested,  well and good. Else, you can post your specific question in site like this, wherein we would try our best to  provide solutions.

This iterative learning and feedback mechanism would hold you in good stead. Also there are several questions which appear in this site which you may be in a position to answer, with the knowledge you have gained after having walked-through the books you mentioned in your question. Give them a try when you have time. Thus in short at this stage, experiential learning is the 'special learning resource' you can try  which would guide you towards the other relevant resources you may need in future.

Answer (score 0):

we run two very popular online workshops  on Selenium that you could attend and also various free one hour workshops. Take a look at our website: http://www.time2test.co.uk or at http://www.time2test.co.uk/2012/04/27/free-one-hour-latest-workshops/

regards Viresh , Time2test Limited, UK

Answer (score 0):

There are some links that might help you on the ["Tutorials and Related Blog Posts"](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/tutorials-and-related-blog-posts) wiki page of Cucumber.

Especially the blog post about ["Testing a web application with Selenium 2"](http://thomassundberg.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/testing-a-web-application-with-selenium-2/) by Thomas Sundberg might be helpful. It starts out with recording, but then explains how to simplify the generated automation code, how to use the Page Object Pattern, how to take screenshots on failure, and finally, it gives some useful hints about code readability and behaviour-driven design.